# Padding a multiline C macro in vim

Tags: vim

I have C macros like:

```
#define  MY_MACRO() \
            xxxxx xxxxxxx \
            xxxxxx xxxxxxx \
            xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx \
            xxxxx                   \
                xxxxxx xxxxxxx                \
                xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxx x \
                        xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
                    x   xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
                xxxxxx x xxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxx \
            x \
            xxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  \
                           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx  \
                 xxxxx \
            xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x \
            x xx xx xxxxxxx
```

And I'm trying to pad them to:

```
#define  MY_MACRO()                                                            \
            xxxxx xxxxxxx                                                      \
            xxxxxx xxxxxxx                                                     \
            xx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx                            \
            xxxxx                                                              \
                xxxxxx xxxxxxx                                                 \
                xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxx x                              \
                        xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                              \
                    x   xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                      \
                xxxxxx x xxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x xxxxxx x xxxxxxxxx                \
            x                                                                  \
            xxx x xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                              \
                           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx                       \
                 xxxxx                                                         \
            xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx x                         \
            x xx xx xxxxxxx
```

The lines should be 80 chars total.

```
'<,'>s/\(.*[^\s]\)\s*\\\s*$/\=printf('%-79s\', submatch(1))
```

mostly does it, except for lines such as:

```
        xxxxxx xxxxxxx                                                                              \
```

that exceed the 80 char limit to star with.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printf()` *width* specifier only adds padding to **increase** the string. If it is already larger than the width, it does not cut off anything.

Your regular expression attempts to limit the matching by excluding trailing whitespace from the match group. Unfortunately, this does not work: `[^\s]`. You cannot use atoms like `\w` inside a *collection*. Either use the corresponding character class (`[^[:white:]]`), or, if available, the negated atom: `\S`. With this fix, your substitution works just fine:

```
'<,'>s/\(.*\S\)\s*\\\s*$/\=printf('%-79s\', submatch(1))
```